# How to handle asynchronous input and synchronous output?

Tags: c, asynchronous, synchronization, stm32, microcontroller

I am currently working on a project where I have USART input and SAI(Serial Audio Interface, similar to SPI) output on an STM32 system.

I created a circular buffer which act as pinpong buffer(double buffer) structure. The input samples which received from USART are stored in this buffer where the head pointer points. When SAI peripheral requests new data, data is pulled from this buffer's tail pointer.

At the start of my code I wait until half the buffer is filled then activate SAI. SAI outputs at constant rate which is 40kHz. Input samples are received from external device's USART at approximately at same rate 40kHz.

Ideally, I expect the difference between my head and tail pointer to be constant.

I also implemented a protection mechanism which makes the Tail pointer wait and output the last sample from SAI until half of the buffer to fill when two pointers are pointing at same location.

The code works at start. The problem is when some time passes like approximately 2 minutes we see the head and tail pointers are pointing at the same location which creates discontinuity in our samples. Which means the one pointer is slow or fast than expected. I am sure of SAI protocol outputting 40kHz constantly (I checked it with scope). However, I am not so sure about accuracy of USARTs timing. I cannot modify the external USART device's code and I cannot change the output rate 40kHz it must be this value.

Is there a another way (maybe other than ping pong buffer method) to handle asynchronous input and synchronous outputs?

Comment: Is it possible the serial port is simply delivering data faster than you can clock it out the SAI?

Comment: @Steve Yes, faster or slower it is probably the problem. Our measurements show 22 samples difference each second.

Comment: So if the source is delivering 22 samples per second faster than can be consumed, then this suggests your memory buffer is on the order of ~2k samples. If this is audio, then you can probably drop a sample now and then, so there's probably an algorithm to do this without the listener noticing.

Comment: Is there another way you can think of? Because SAI drives a RF modulator chip which sends information through phase of the sampled signal. So dropping samples causes phase to mess up. Unfortunately, I cannot drop samples.

Comment: Hmmm. I had started writing an Answer post on how to do this, but if you can't drop samples, then you have to figure out why your input is .05% fast, or perhaps use a larger ring buffer if these are not continuous transmissions.   This sounds like a tough problem.

Comment: USART transmission is continous and it supposed to send data each 25us (40kHz). I tried using larger ring buffer but it only delays the inevitable.

Comment: "Supposed to" is such a cute term :-) Is it possible to do some kind of clock synchronization between the two units?

Comment: I've done this in commercial products for realtime hidef H.264 audio/video encoding/decoding, and particular emphasis on audio sync. The output _must_ maintain the cadence. If the input produces fewer samples than the output needs, you inject dummy samples (e.g. 0). If the output produces too much, you drop _input_ samples. But, the output sample rate _must_ be constant.

Comment: Ring buffer code can be tricky. Based on your description, it is possible that the ring queue code drops a sample (i.e. it has a bug). Can you _edit_ your question and post the relevant code. You may wish to keep a log of arrivals from USART with timestamps to see if it's "bursty" (ironically, such a trace buffer [similar to `dtrace`] is often implemented with a ring buffer).

Comment: @SteveFriedl Unfortunetly I cannot modify the other unit or get the clock signal from other unit to synchronize my clock to it. However, I will try doing that in LAB tests to see if this is the actual problem or it helps.

Comment: @CraigEstey I have measured the signal. Signal output seems to be fine for 2 minutes intervals. After two minutes the signal outputs the last sample until half of the buffer is full. Then signal is okay another 2 minutes. So I don't think ring queue drops a sample.

Comment: Your application is similar to a video/audio decoder [that uses UDP]. They must keep the output sample rate constant, even if input packets are corrupted, missing or delayed. If corrupted/missing, the output must add dummy samples. But, if the output has added dummies, and _later_ the actual data arrives, the output must drop/ignore these _real_ samples because they have no place to go because of the already output dummies.

Comment: It seems to me that, there is no easy solutions here. I have to either synchronize clocks between two units or drop/add dummy samples. Synchronizing clocks is worth to try since dropping or adding dummy samples mess up the phase.

Comment: Again, please post your ring queue code, ISR code, dequeue code and output [to RF] code. It is possible to have a latent race condition between ISR and base level that causes the behavior you are seeing. This assumes that the input rate matches the [desired] output rate. If they aren't exact (they drift over some period of time [e.g. 2 minutes ;-)]), you'll need the inject/drop code I spoke of.

Comment: No. The inject/drop _maintains_ precise phase [what I was calling cadence]. You probably _can't_ sync the clocks. There will always be some drift. Commercial encode/decode equipment assumes this and constantly resyncs to a master clock or compensates in other ways. They [must] run continuously for months [or years] and always maintain a constant output stream/rate.

Comment: You cannot synch clocks.  Even with a very accurate external oscillator, tolerance is 10, 50ppm at least.  Give up on perfect synching unless BOTH devices operate off the same oscillator, period.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are saying is you are receiving (continuous) serial data from some external device, and then you are forwarding it out some interface of your own at some rate...based on your clock.  Even if the data is the same format and the clocks are "the same", then a buffer overflow is expected somewhere.

Same thing happens with ethernet or any other source if 1) continuous at line rate 2) source for the input and source for the output are a different clock 3) there are guaranteed to be differences in the reference clocks, if the input source clock is a little faster then so long as the stream stays continuous and at line rate, then you will overflow eventually.

The clocks change with temperature and voltage so the delta can change.

Possible to even reduce the percentage of the data you output from the input and still overflow if the input is continuous.  Depends on if your output is also at line rate or of you have margin and the margin can overcome the difference in the clocks.

Also remember uarts hardly run at that exact rate, the use clock dividers and get close, you can have two computers using uarts at the same rate and the delta can be relatively large and the overflow can happen very soon.  For uart to work the clock has to only be good enough to get through one character so can be several percent off if not more than that, even if the oscillator is very good and no plls and both sides use the same reference clock (but not the same uart, clocking system, etc).

If you increase your output rate or reduce the data being output so that it is not at line rate then the problem may go away or may take hours or days before it happens...

if I have misunderstood the problem, forgive me, I will delete this answer.